# Event undefined for event.preventDefault in a React form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to create a user authentication page using React and Apollo.  I'm getting that my event is undefined for `onClick` event for the following code:

```
const Auth = props => {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
    const onSubmitHandler = async (login, e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const authResults = await login()
        props.history.push('/')
    }
    return (
        <Mutation 
            mutation={LOGIN}
            variables={{ email, password }}
        >
        {(login, {data, error, loading}) => {
            if(loading) return <div>...loading</div>
            if(error) return <div>Error</div>
            return (
                <form onSubmit={onSubmitHandler}>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label htmlFor="email">
                            Email
                        </label>
                        <input 
                            type="email" 
                            id="email"
                            value={email}
                            onChange={e => {
                                setEmail(e.target.value)
                            }}
                        />
                    </fieldset>
                    <fieldset>
                        <label htmlFor="password">
                            Password
                        </label>
                        <input 
                            type="password" 
                            id="password"
                            value={password}
                            onChange={e => {
                                setPassword(e.target.value)
                            }}
                        />
                    </fieldset>
                    <button>Login</button>
                </form>
                )
            }}
        </Mutation>
    )
```

I tried including the variables at the point of invocation as following:

```
<form onSubmit={(login, e) => onSubmitHandler(login, e)}>
```

But, to no avail.

Edit: The initial issue has been resolved, but when I refactored the code to utilize react-apollo-hooks, I keep getting the following errors:

```
Variable "$email" of required type "String!" was not provided
Variable "$password" of required type "String!" was not provided
```

My refactored codes are as follows:

```
const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
const variables = {
    data: { email, password }
}
const login = useMutation(LOGIN_MUTATION, {
    variables
})

const onSubmitHandler = async (login, e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const authResults = await login()
    localStorage.setItem(AUTH_TOKEN, authResults.data.login.token);
    props.history.push('/') 
}
```

The graphql mutation

```
const LOGIN_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation Login($email: String!, $password: String!) {
    login(data: {
        email: $email, password: $password
        }
    ){
      token
      user {
        id
      }
    }
  }
`
```

My schema

login(data: LoginUserInput!): AuthPayload!

Comment: It should be `<form onSubmit={e => onSubmitHandler(login, e)}>`, the `login` comes from the rendered props

Comment: wow, worked like a charm. Thank you!